# Is it possible to manually set when the Api will be called on google react maps package

Tags: reactjs, google-maps-api-3

I am using the google maps react package and it can be found here https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps-react.

It works well for the most part but I am trying to render my maps conditionally based on the user agreement. The API always loads on render. I was wondering if there was a way to make it not load except my user has agreed for the map to show and that access is there. The docs don't really say anything about conditionally loading or rendering the API.

https://github.com/fullstackreact/google-maps-react/issues/390

Comment: So the api loads even when you don't show the map?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski exactly. I only want it to load when the map is shown